# add request.user to serialized data

Tags: python, django, rest, serialization, django-rest-framework

iam created api request for creating a entity with collected data

##### my view is like this

```
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
@api_view(["POST"])
def createAppoinment(req):
    appoinment=CreateAppoinmentSerializer(data=req.data)
    if appoinment.is_valid():
        appoinment.save()

        return Response(appoinment.data,status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    print(appoinment.data,"this is appoinment")
    
    return Response(appoinment.errors,status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
```

##### and my serializer is like this

```
class CreateAppoinmentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model=Appoinment
        fields=['applicant_name','submission_date','appoinment_date',
                'care_of','phone','appoinment_time','pass_seva_username',
                'pass_seva_password','office','agency','paid','net_amo
```

my model have additional foreign key field **`owner`** and a **`onetoone`** field, transaction how can i add the owner field and transaction field to to serilizer for create new entity

i want to save datas from the front end in data base but i dont know how to add user and other foreign keys to serialization

Answer (score 0):

You can save Foreign key instance at saving Serializer like this...

##### views.py

```
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
@api_view(["POST"])
def createAppoinment(req):
    appoinment=CreateAppoinmentSerializer(data=req.data)
    if appoinment.is_valid():
        onetoone= OnetooneModel.obects.get(id= request.data.get('id_of_onetoone'))
        appoinment.save(user=request.user, onetoone = onetoone)
        return Response(appoinment.data,status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    print(appoinment.data,"this is appoinment")
    
    return Response(appoinment.errors,status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
```